# url rewriting gives "object not found" error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Below is my original url

```
http://localhost/mysite/mainarticle?article_id=84
```

RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^/article/([0-9]+) /mainarticle?article_id=$1 [L]
```

new url

```
http://localhost/mysite/article/84
```

When I use the `new url` it gives the `Object not found` error. Seems like my rewrite rule is not working. Need your help if I'm using the rule correctly or changes are needed.

**Note:**

I'm using additional rules as well to hide extentions.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using absolute paths, but `/mysite/` isn't the document root, so that won't work. Remove the leading slashes to use relative paths and you should be good.

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+) mainarticle?article_id=$1 [L]
```

As it's an internal redirect you can also safely add the `.php` extension in case you know that's the file you are targeting, this would avoid an additional rewrite for the missing extension.

```
... mainarticle.php?article_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: salute this genius, this problem ruined my 3 hours