# RewriteRule The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have same problem :
[url rewriting gives "object not found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554802/url-rewriting-gives-object-not-found-error)

but I'm using sub-domain and it doesn't work ...

**My Original URL :**

`Http://wiki.example.com/articles/index.php?user=Martin&pass=Cohle`

I've placed htaccess file in

> "wiki.example.com/htdocs/articles/";

**RewriteRule**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^wiki_article/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$ index.php?user=$1&pass=$2[L]
```

**new url**
`wiki.example.com/wiki_article/Martin/Cohle/`

I get :

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

What I did wrong ?

Comment: Is `^wiki_article/...` a typo or part of the actual code? Because that regular expression is not going to match any of the urls in your question.

Comment: @SteveE. sorry ! fixed.